# Обработка Fetch запроса на сервере Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Проблема с обработкой fetch запроса. Имеется некая html страница и к ней прикручен скрипт. В скрипте с помощью fetch я считываю форму и отправляю по урле, которую на сервере ноды слушают и пытаюсь понять, что мне прислал клиент

Сделал заглушку, что бы проверить, как приходит ответ.

Внешний скрипт (который подключен к HTML странице, которую вызывает Node js)

```
fetch("/user",{
    method: "POST",
    body: "test",
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "text/plain"
    }
})
.then((res)=>{
    return res.text();
})
```

На сервере (Node.js + Express) ловлю ответ

```
app.post('/user', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body);
})
```

И получаю udefined.

Может кто-то сталкивался с таким? или есть рабочий пример отправки-приема fetch на стороне node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-умолчанию, `express` не обрабатывает тело POST запросов. Вам нужно подключить модуль [`body-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```
$ npm i body-parser
```

Он имеет обработчики различных `content-type` тела запроса. Для обработки тестовых данных `text/plain` нужно подключить `bodyParser.text`

```
app.use(bodyParser.text())
```

Все обработчики, подключённые далее, будут корректно обрабатывать тело post запроса.

Comment: Да, дело было в парсере. Спасибо за ответ